# Check OpenVPN's connection status

Tags: c#, performance, design-patterns

I wrote a method that will start OpenVPN on a config file, and then wait to be connected.

It relies on OpenVPN using *Local Area Connection 2*, which hurts code reusability, but I'm not sure how to do it any other way.

```
private static async void StartOpenVPN(string configFile)
{
    // Start OpenVPN on the config file...
    Process.Start("openvpn-gui", $"--connect {configFile}");

    // OpenVPN uses Local Area Connection 2.
    var adapter =
        NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .First(networkInterface => networkInterface.Name == "Local Area Connection 2");

    // Wait for Local Area Connection 2 to be operational...
    while (adapter.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        adapter =
            NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                .First(networkInterface => networkInterface.Name == "Local Area Connection 2");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
}
```

Is there a more effective/efficient/elegant way to start OpenVPN on a config file, and then wait to be connected?

Comment: Single responsibility... your function is doing more than it says it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the Gateway or Unicast IP Address

For the case of checking if the VPN Connection is online or not, you could consider a solution that just returns a boolean value.

Secondly, I wouldn't do it by connection name, instead how about using either the gateway IP address or the unicast IP address?

```
public class OpenVpnConnection
{
    private IPAddress _gatewayIpAddress;
    private IPAddress _unicastIpAddress;

    public OpenVpnConnection()
    {
        _gatewayIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.1");
        _unicastIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.101");
    }

    public bool IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            return false;

        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            // discard because of standard reasons
            if (ni.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up) continue;
            if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) continue;
            //if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel) continue;

            // discard if the interface is not "virtual"
            //if (ni.Description.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <= 0) continue;
            //if (ni.Name.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <= 0) continue;

            if (GetIpFromGatewayAddresses(ni).Contains(_gatewayIpAddress)) return true;
            if (GetIpFromUnicastAddresses(ni).Contains(_unicastIpAddress)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetIpFromGatewayAddresses(NetworkInterface nic)
    {
        return nic.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses
            .Where(ip => ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            .Select(ip => ip.Address);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetIpFromUnicastAddresses(NetworkInterface nic)
    {
        return nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
            .Where(ip => ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            .Select(ip => ip.Address);
    }
}
```

You can take out sections of the code that you don't need, but I included both unicast and gateway options above.

You would then simply check if the connection is online by

```
var vpn = new OpenVpnConnection();
bool online = vpn.IsNetworkAvailable();
```

of course, you'll want to pass parameters and what-not, but this is simply to illustrate the idea of moving away from the connection name and using an IP address instead.

---

### Putting it together

A quick and dirty way of piecing it together with you current code would look something like this

```
private static async void StartOpenVPN(string configFile)
{
    // Start OpenVPN on the config file...
    Process.Start("openvpn-gui", $"--connect {configFile}");


    var vpn = new OpenVpnConnection(); //of course, send parameters in your actual code
    while (!vpn.IsNetworkAvailable)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
}
```

Rather than using a loop, you could consider using the [NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead.

Comment: Even though I'm not going to use anything you wrote (thanks though), I'm marking this as the answer because of the **unicast address idea**, and because **you made me realize how clunky my "wait until connected loop" was**.

Comment: @Owen I'm glad that I brought some good ideas forward.

Comment: @Owen On further thought, may I recommend to consider thinking about using a gateway address (instead of unicast)? I feel that the gateway address is usually more static/reliable overall versus a client address, as it is more resilient to reconnects, self-assigned addresses, NAT and other routing-related issues.

Comment: I'll look into using the gateway address instead, thanks! I'm not very experienced with anything network related, so I appreciate the advice. :)